# Does it qualify for NaA flag?

Tags: support, not-an-answer

I can remember one of my *Not an Answer* flags was disputed once, then I did read about answer flags and learned that an answer may be allowed to stay unless it **clearly** isn't constructive, on-topic or otherwise valid.

I have just come across such an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29024504/4490187 .

In my opinion it is pointless, does not answer anything, generates another question and appears to be chatty. However, it does not seemingly violate any of **SO** rules, correct me if I'm wrong.

Also, it's easy to notice that the author of that answer hasn't read the *Tour* page and appears to have posted that answer immediately after registering their account, though it does not look like spam.

Does it qualify for *Not an Answer* flag?

Comment: It violates SO rule of answers being answers by not being an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It absolutely qualifies as NAA, and it looks as though it's about to be deleted. Here's a copy of its content for posterity:

> Quite an easy question you've asked. Let's complicate it a little bit.
>
> What is minimum number of matches required to find top 'n' teams out of 'x' teams? (x>n)

This is absolutely not an answer.  While *in some cases* it's appropriate to answer a question with a simple question, or a series of questions, that'll lead the reader to the answer (i.e, the [Socratic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method)), that clearly isn't what's going on here. Indeed, the new question that's being raised is significantly more complicated than the original one. (The "answer" admits that they're "complicating it", too, so it's not as though this could even be a failed attempt to lead the reader to the answer.)

As an aside, the question is off-topic anyways. It's essentially a logic problem, unrelated to programming. I've started a vote to close it.